# GlassFish session id when first time site is loading

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, glassfish

Here is the problem. I get the `sessionId` with:

```
request.getRequestedSessionId();
```

However when site is opening first time it returns null. Only starting with second visit it returns session id. But I need to know from first time. Can I get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's null because there is no session.

Consider instead:

```
request.getSession(true).getId()
```

which will create a session if one does not exist, then provides a unique session identifier.